Why does my feature branch show '1 commit ahead, 1 commit behind' after rebase and merge?
After running the following commands:
git checkout feature
git add .
git commit -m "done"
git push

Over on GitHub, it shows that feature branch is 1 commit ahead of main, I believe the graph looks something like this:
*(main)
   \
    \
     - - *(feature)

I then merged the pull request from feature into main using the "rebase and merge" option.
However, after merging, the feature branch now shows:
This branch is 1 commit ahead of, 1 commit behind main

I expected the main and feature branches to be in sync at this point, with a graph like this:
*
 \
  \
   - - *(main,feature)

The graph actually looks like this:

Why does this discrepancy occur?

What does the commit graph actually look like? I suppose that will answer your question.

could you share the direct link of the repo?

"after merging, the feature branch now shows: ..." - where does it show that?

For an in depth explanation of what "1 commit ahead, 1 commit behind" means see the first part of this answer. Whatever tool you currently use for history visualization, you should at minimum supplement with using gitk --all in addition, but you really should use gitk as your everyday git history visualization tool.

See also this answer.

Rebasing a commit means making a new commit with the same changes as the old one, but that can be on top of a different parent commit. Any differences between two commits will result in them having completely different hashes and being treated as totally separate by Git. The 1 commit ahead of "feature" is the original commit you made with git commit -m "done", and the 1 commit behind is the commit that GitHub made by rebasing.
